# Enter data in one field and have another field update automatically

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have an Access table named Issues with a Date field and Status field in the same table. The status field is a combo box with list value of "Open" or "Closed". I would like to enter a date in the date field and automatically change the status field from "Open" to "Closed". So, when the user enters the date in the form it will change the status to "Closed" automatically.

Comment: You gave us a question without adequate detail.. What role do the dates play? Are you trying to query your table and if there's a date we change the status? What about dates not in the table?

Comment: The dates play the role of closing out the form. For example all customer issue data will be entered in the form and at the bottom of the form is the Date the issue was corrected, and once that date is entered I need the Status to change to Closed. I'm not sure how to Query the table and make sure the Query runs everytime the date is entered to change status. Also, the dates not in the table should remain as Open until a date is entered. Thanks for your assistance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the only factor affecting the [Status] value is whether or not a value exists in the date field then you could simply make [Status] a calculated field in the table:

[image: CalculatedField.png]

That way the [Status] value would always be updated at the table level and you wouldn't have to add any special code to your forms, update queries, etc..

Comment: Thanks for the help your suggestion works as intended. I would like to learn expression in ms access do you know of any good resources I can familiar myself with? Thanks again